# Display a large text in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I would like to display a large text (a string to be precise) in MATLAB . I am currently using following code:

```
fig = figure(3);
hPan = uipanel(fig,'Units','normalized');
uicontrol(hPan, 'Style','text','HorizontalAlignment','center', ...
'FontSize',25, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1], ...
'String',decodedValue);
```

But since `uicontrol` doesn't support `VerticalAlignment`, my output is currently stuck to the top of the figure whereas I would like to make it centered:

[image]

Is there perhaps any alternative way that I could display a large text in MATLAB?

Comment: Can we assume editing the size of the the position is not an option here?

Comment: @patrik Anything is possible as long as I could make my string get printed nice and neat in the center of figure. So you are suggesting to print the text couple of lines lower. Right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is how Matlab means it to be done. Further, do you think it is reasonable to have a textbox, which covers the whole figure? That could lead to complications (like that the textbox cover other kinds of information) forcing you do write unnecessary and advanced figure handling mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [position](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html?searchHighlight=position) and size of your uicontrol text field to be in the center of your figure:

```
decodedValue = 'Decoded Value: 2';

fig = figure(3);
hPan = uipanel(fig,'Units','normalized');

uicontrol(hPan, 'Style','text', 'HorizontalAlignment','center', ...
'FontSize',25, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.2 0.4 0.6 0.2], ...
'String',decodedValue);
```

The position vector has the following meaning: `[left bottom width height]`: The figure / text element starts at `left bottom` and has a size of `width height`